# Replacing the existing values of a numpy array with strings and numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to manipulate some numpy arrays but have no idea how can I solve it. My primary data set is like

`a= [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

I want to embed some characters and numbers to it. I want to have my result like bellow:

```
b= [[Point(1) = {1, 2, 3}], [Point(2) = {4, 5, 6}]]
```

In fact, I want to replace the first and column of each row with a fixed string (`Point(n) = {`) and the number of row and also the primary value. I mean `1` should become `Point(1) = {1`.
Another change is also for the last column and I want simply add a curved bracket after the value of primary data in all the rows (in reality I have thousands of rows).
In advance, I appreciate any help and feedback,
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking at something like this:

```
def func(a):
    n = 1
    for x, y, z in a:
        print('Point ({}) = {{{}, {}, {}}}'.format(n, x, y, z))
        print('Point ({}) = {{{}'.format(n, x))
        print('{}'.format(y))
        print('{}}}'.format(z))
        n+=1
```

Though it is totally not my place, you might also wish to consider looking at the pandas package to help you manage data. There might be some tips there to prevent such difficult to handle data =)